# How to set gradient background transparency on iOS Safari?

Tags: ios, css, mobile-safari

The following CSS doesn`t function on Safari (tested on iPad iOS):

```
.map-left-navi {
    background: #ffffff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 35%, transparent 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 35%,transparent 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 35%,transparent 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='transparent',GradientType=1 );
}
```

Any idea on a workaround to keep the transparency?

Edit - **Solution:**

Use rgba CSS color values:

```
.map-left-navi {
    background: #ffffff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255, 0.35), rgba(255,255,255, 0));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255, 0.35), rgba(255,255,255, 0));
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255, 0.35), rgba(255,255,255, 0));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='transparent',GradientType=1 );
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use rgba instead of transparent.

```
.map-left-navi {
    background: #ffffff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255, 0.35), rgba(255,255,255, 0));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255, 0.35), rgba(255,255,255, 0));
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255, 0.35), rgba(255,255,255, 0));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='transparent',GradientType=1 );
}
```