# transparent show black color on IOS 14 and up

Tags: html, css

When I use for example

```
.packages > .ulWrapper::after {
  background: linear-gradient(
    to left,
    var(--edge-color) 5%,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 95%
  ); /* way 1 - show red */

  background: linear-gradient(
    to left,
    var(--edge-color) 5%,
    transparent 95%
  ); /* => way 1 - show black */

  background: linear-gradient(
    to left,
    var(--edge-color) 5%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 95%
  ); /* => way 1 - show black */

  background: linear-gradient(
    to left,
    var(--edge-color) 5%,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 95%
  ); /* => way 1 - show white */
  
}
```

I just want to be transparent on one side how can I apply it on the iPhone?
everything I try to do doesn't show me transparent on iPhone please help.

I try to do it by this one *[How to set gradient background transparency on iOS Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48311641/how-to-set-gradient-background-transparency-on-ios-safari)*

I add a small [link](https://codepen.io/lichaytiram/pen/rNjLrLJ) to show my problem more clearly.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}
div.first {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, pink 5%, transparent 50%);
}
div.second {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, pink 5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

Comment: Could you put up a complete snippet which shows the problem. We don’t know for example whether there are any other settings which may be coming into play.

Comment: It impossible to show the problem because it happened only on IOS

Comment: Thank you for putting up the link (better if it was in a snippet in the actual question for future readers - but it's OK for me). I have tried on Edge/Chrome and on IOS (iPad) and they look the same - except the iPad shows brighter. I am getting transparency on the left hand side - checked against the real background color.

Comment: can you send a picture because on my iPhone I see black transparent instead real transparent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the 'transparent' keyword, use the pink color in RGB with full transparent:

```
rgb(255 192 203 / 0%) /* transparent pink */
```

This will solve your problem.

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/362c8319f22cb8915452ab3701d2545f) (the third option is my own solution)

Comment: Actually it seems that there is a problem with full transparency at all. Using this fix you gave here actually showed a light pink in my case. I simply used the color I needed (so not only pink works) but it will never be fully transparent. Thanks for the fix though +1 :)